# $f$ has simple pole at origin. Compare $\rm Res (f,0)$ with $\rm Res (f(1/f), 0 )$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm preparing for a qualifying exam (instead of working assignments I have due now) and I have a small question about a problem that was on a past qualifying exam:

> Suppose $f$ has a simple pole at the origin, and $g$ denotes $1/f$ (the reciprocal function). How is the residue at the origin of the composite function $f\circ g$ related to the residue at the origin of $f$?

I have a possible solution. I'm just just unsure of it:

Since $f$ is holomorphic in a small enough annulus of the origin it has a convergent Laurent series centered at $z=0$, i.e.,
$$
\frac{c_{-1}}{z}+c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2+\cdots
$$
for $c_{-1},c_0,\ldots\in\mathbb{C}$. However, in a small enough annulus, $f\simeq c_{-1}/z$. Therefore
$$
f\circ g=f\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)\simeq f\left(\frac{1}{\frac{c_1}{z}}\right)=f\left(\frac{z}{c_1}\right)=\frac{c_{-1}}{\left(\frac{z}{c_{-1}}\right)}=\frac{(c_{-1})^2}{z}
$$
and $($Res$(f,0))^2=$Res$(f\circ g,0)$.

Is there something wrong in working with $c_{-1}/z$ instead of the full Laurent series? Would I at least have to work with
$$
f(z)=\frac{c_{-1}}{z}+c_0+\mathcal{O}(z)?
$$
I tend to be afraid of working with approximations but if we're in small enough annulus it shouldn't make a difference (right?). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are doing fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is evaluate the behavior of

$$c_{-1} \left (\frac{c_{-1}}{z}+c_0+c_1 z+\cdots \right ) +c_0 + \frac{c_1 }{\frac{c_{-1}}{z}+c_0+c_1 z+\cdots}+ \cdots$$

as $|z| \to 0$.  The dominant behavior I get is

$$f \left ( \frac1{f(z)} \right )  = \frac{c_{-1}^2}{z} + c_0 (c_{-1}+1) + c_1 \left (c_{-1}+\frac1{c_{-1}} \right ) z+ O \left (z^2 \right )$$

Note that all neglected orders must be at least quadratic in $z$.  I imagine on a qualifying exam, you will need to show this is true within any arbitrarily small annulus.  Thus, as was shown,

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0} \left [ f \left ( \frac1{f(z)} \right ) \right ] = c_{-1}^2$$

and you have the tools to evaluate the full Laurent series.

Comment: Thank you! This explanation is more involved than what I was going with, and provides more insight.